# Article the with the word space

Tags: grammar

When you use the word "space"(outer space in the universe), it seems that no definite article goes with the word. However, I wonder if that is really how it is, there is no occasion you would ever use the article "the"?

> We entered into **space**.
>   What planet haven't we explored yet in **this vast space**?
>   (Later on, back on Earth) I will never forget **the** space I went in....

Is "the" possible for the word space in that context?

Comment: Did you even do a Google search to see if there is any usage like what you ask about? In "in this vast space" and "I will never forget 'the' space I went in....", *space* does not mean *outer space* specifically, just some area of space around you. You need to check for "**the** outer space" not other variations.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of an instance when the word 'Space', meaning outer space, out in the Universe, would be used with an article.

It might be helpful to think of it in this way - in this particular usage, the word 'space' is being used like we use the name of a continent (like Africa) or a country (like France).  In English, you would not say "When I went to the Africa", or "When I returned from the France".  You would say "When I went to Africa" and "when I returned from France".

It's the same idea with "Space" (when the word is used to describe 'out there in the Universe, not on Earth').

Comment: Thank you. Then how about the definite article with this context?(I presumed that it doesn't need the article, but the speaker used it): A: who has been doing the balancing? B: the balance beasty. The name of the animal is Balance beasty and there is only one existing. Why do you think the speaker B used the article?

Answer (score 0):

If an author were talking about (outer) space, it would not be appropriate to use a definite article. If, however, the author was referring to a space (like that area between two trees), it would be appropriate to call it “the space” between (those) two trees. It is hard to know *which* space is indicated in the last sentence, because of the use of ellipses (“…”).